# How can I change my function inputs with chracter array

Tags: c, function, embedded, keil, hal

Hello every one I am writing an embedded C code on STM32Fxx micro processors with Keil MicroVision IDE. In my project I am using 8 piece of relay. I decleared each of my relays with following code sample.

```
 #define DO9_Pin GPIO_PIN_14
 #define DO9_GPIO_Port GPIOC
 #define DO8_Pin GPIO_PIN_15
 #define DO8_GPIO_Port GPIOC
 #define DO7_Pin GPIO_PIN_1
 #define DO7_GPIO_Port GPIOA
 #define DO6_Pin GPIO_PIN_0
 #define DO6_GPIO_Port GPIOA
 #define DO5_Pin GPIO_PIN_7
 #define DO5_GPIO_Port GPIOB
 #define DO4_Pin GPIO_PIN_6
 #define DO4_GPIO_Port GPIOB
 #define DO3_Pin GPIO_PIN_5
 #define DO3_GPIO_Port GPIOB
 #define DO2_Pin GPIO_PIN_1
 #define DO2_GPIO_Port GPIOB
 #define DO1_Pin GPIO_PIN_4
 #define DO1_GPIO_Port GPIOA
 #define DO0_Pin GPIO_PIN_3
 #define DO0_GPIO_Port GPIOA`
```

After that I  adjusted the Relay status("GPIO PIN STATUS") with well known with HAL Functions. For example  in each cylce I am setting the status of my 9 relays with the microcontrollers pins for this I am using this code block `

```
  void prsSetResetRelays(unsigned char coilNo,char status){

    if(coilNo==0){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO0_GPIO_Port,DO0_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
       }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO0_GPIO_Port,DO0_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==1){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO1_GPIO_Port,DO1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO1_GPIO_Port,DO1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==2){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO2_GPIO_Port,DO2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO2_GPIO_Port,DO2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==3){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO3_GPIO_Port,DO3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO3_GPIO_Port,DO3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }else if(coilNo==4){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO4_GPIO_Port,DO4_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO4_GPIO_Port,DO4_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }else if(coilNo==5){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO5_GPIO_Port,DO5_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO5_GPIO_Port,DO5_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==6){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO6_GPIO_Port,DO6_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO6_GPIO_Port,DO6_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==7){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO7_GPIO_Port,DO7_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO7_GPIO_Port,DO7_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
    else if(coilNo==8){
        if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO8_GPIO_Port,DO8_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else{
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO8_GPIO_Port,DO8_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
      else if(coilNo==9){
          if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO9_GPIO_Port,DO9_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }else{
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO9_GPIO_Port,DO9_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
         }
      }

    }
```

My question is this. Is there any way for me to doing that to reduce this code in a shorter form. Can I use a for cycle,instead of  this all statements. For example I would like to write a code like :`

```
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
           if(status=='s' || status=='S'){
                  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO[i]_GPIO_Port,DO[i]_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }else{
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DO[i]_GPIO_Port,DO[i]_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
         }
       }
```

Is there any way for me to doing this kind of notation in c programming language. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot index into preprocessor names, no. They are not runtime variables, they are strictly used to do text replacement before the compiler even sees the code.

The proper solution is to model your array of relays as, well, an array:

```
static const struct {
  GPIO_TypeDef *port;
  uint16_t     pin;
} relays[] = {
 { GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14 },
 { GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15 },
 ... more here ...
};
```

Then you can use an index into the array to get the port/pin data, and poke it:

```
void prsSetResetRelays(unsigned char coilNo, char status)
{
  if(coilNo >= sizeof relays / sizeof *relays)
    return;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(relays[coilNo].port, relays[coilNo].pin,
    (status == 's' || status == 'S') ? GPIO_PIN_SET : GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort